# How to make smooth gradients in regular command prompt using python?

Tags: python, colors

So, I'd like to have 256 colors in regular command prompt. Tool called "Kraken Grabber" has it, but it's obfuscated. Looks like this:
[Kraken Grabber screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHbx9.png)

How do I achieve this result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) to achieve Truecolor:

```py
from rich.console import Console
console = Console()
console.print("[#FF00FF]Hello[/] [#FFFF00]World[/]")
```